# which library contains regexec(), regfree(), regcomp()?

Tags: c++, g++

Could anyone please tell me which library to use to avail the regexec(), regfree() and regcomp() functions ? I know they are defined in the regex.h header file but even after including the header file I am getting a linker error saying unsatisfied symbol when I am trying to compile a code in HP-UX.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a complete guess, [`-lregex`](https://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=undefined%20reference%20to%20regexec).

Answer (score 1):

We recently hit this bug in HP-UX 11 when trying to compile using g++. Somehow, the linked mixes up the posix-compatible libraries and HP-UX's own system libraries.

If you are trying to compile C++ code which uses regexp.h, use the "aCC" compiler, NOT "g++".